# How to get relative dates

Tags: objective-c, relative-date

how can I get relative dates in Objective-C?

If I have "today", how do I find "yesterday", "last week", "last two weeks", "one month ago", "two months ago"?

Comment: Really not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 10):

So if you have an `NSDate *today = [NSDate date];`, then you can use [`NSDateComponents`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to get relative dates.

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSDateComponents *yesterdayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[yesterdayComponents setDay:-1];
NSDate *yesterday = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:yesterdayComponents toDate:today options:0];
[yesterdayComponents release];

NSDateComponents *twoWeeksAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[twoWeeksAgoComponents setWeek:-2];
NSDate *twoWeeksAgo = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:twoWeeksAgoComponents toDate:today options:0];
[twoWeeksAgoComponents release];
```

Etc.

`NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` handle underflowing and overflowing automatically (unless you turn it off with the `options:` bit).  So if today is "28 February" and you want "tomorrow", it will automatically choose either "29 February" or "1 March" depending on the year.  It's pretty cool.  This is also **the only proper way of doing date manipulation**.

Comment: the weeks not return corrrectly  NSDateComponents *TwoWeeksAgoComponents = [components copy];
 [TwoWeeksAgoComponents setWeek:[TwoWeeksAgoComponents week]-2];
 NSDate *TwoWeeksAgo = [calendar dateFromComponents:TwoWeeksAgoComponents];
 NSLog( [formatter stringFromDate:TwoWeeksAgo] );
 [TwoWeeksAgoComponents release];

Comment: also does NSCalendar depend on the ipad calender , or it's always georgean

Comment: This code does not work; it always returns the initial date.  I had to use `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:`.  I'm assuming all the upvotes on this answer are from people who didn't actually test the code.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy I've updated the code. It should work fine now.

Comment: @DaveDeLong Thanks.  I deleted my answer since it now duplicates yours.